# jQuery Animate - border color and width

Tags: jquery

I cannot seem to get this jQuery animation working for applying a border to an image on `mouseenter`:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/acc96259d6b2678985052c33e05a3062/tumblr_mkv9fhDBDS1rmc58qo1_500.jpg" />
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('div img').mousenter(function(){
    $(this).css({"border": "0px solid #f37736"}).animate({
        'borderWidth': '4px',
        'borderColor: '#f37736'
    },500);
}).mouseleave(function(){
     $(this).animate({
        'borderWidth':'0px',
        'borderColor:'#f37736'
    },500);
});
```

I also tried removing the CSS part for the jQuery, but does not work either

Comment: you're just having couple of typos there. See corrected fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h6jg4/

Comment: Just wondering, don't you have a console in your browser?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`$.animate()` works only on CSS properties that have single numeric values.  Thus, you only need to specify the border's width, as the border-color property is ignored by `$.animate()`.

Other than that, the event is `mouseenter`, not `mousenter`.

Here is the fixed code:

```
$('div img').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).css({border: '0 solid #f37736'}).animate({
        borderWidth: 4
    }, 500);
}).mouseleave(function () {
     $(this).animate({
        borderWidth: 0
    }, 500);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h6jg4/2/)

Comment: isn't there a way I can make the animation smooth, so that the image does not move when the border is applied? I can probably do it by just changing the border color from white(background) to orange but you said that color does not work in .animate()

Comment: @DextrousDave, if you use jQuery UI as well, you can animate the background-color property as well, transitioning from a 4px white background to a 4px orange background.

Answer (score 5):

Change your jQUERY to this

```
$('div img').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).css("border", "0px solid #f37736").animate({
        'borderWidth': '4px',
        'borderColor': '#f37736'
    },500);
}).mouseleave(function(){
     $(this).animate({
        'borderWidth':'0px',
        'borderColor':'#f37736'
    },500);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

jQuery cannot animate color on its own, you need to include a seperate jQuery plugin for that.

Comment: Could you specify which plugin and where to get it?

Comment: @ChaosFreak this question is so old, a lot has changed. nowadays you can animate colors with css transitions.

Comment: Thanks, @Alex. I looked up documentation on CSS transitions and I can't figure out how to trigger them with jQuery. However, the `jquery-ui-color` plugin does exactly what I need.

Comment: you can use jquery or javascript to add or remove classes to elements. via css you can define transitions for those classes, for instance

Answer (score 3):

Fixed code:

http://jsfiddle.net/9qwmX/491/

```
$('div img').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).css({
        outline: "0px solid transparent"
    }).animate({
        outlineWidth: '4px',
         outlineColor: '#f37736'
    }, 500);
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).animate({
         outlineWidth: '0px',
         outlineColor: '#037736'
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: thank you. Any way to make the transition smooth such that the image does not move?

Comment: @roasted, your margin solution makes it less, not more, smooth!

Comment: oops,sorry. But ideally for smooth animation/transition, you should use CSS3, not jquery. :hover CSS pseudo class would be a good start.

Comment: yeah I know, but javascript is better supported (browsers) than CSS3, so I want to stick to it for now

Answer (score 1):

You have some typos in your code

1. `.mousenter` should be `.mouseenter`
2. didnt close the apostrophe in both `'borderColor`. change them to `'borderColor'`

> ```
> $('div img').mouseenter(function(){
>     $(this).css("border", "0px solid #f37736").animate({
>         'borderWidth': '4px',
>         'borderColor': '#f37736'
>     },500);
> }).mouseleave(function(){
>      $(this).animate({
>         'borderWidth':'0px',
>         'borderColor':'#f37736'
>     },500);
> });
> ```