# How to change the border thickness and pulsate bordercolors of an HTML table with jQuery until a click is detected ''elsewhere''?

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script, html-table

I have a GAS Web App that contains a table with `<tr contenteditable="false" id="pmlist'+ index+'">` row tags. I want to create an event to allow the content to be edited and have the border tickness change from `1px` to `3px` and pulsate between black and white for the length of the row(to indicate that this row is being edited),  then when the user clicks anywhere outside the highlighted row, the `contenteditable` is set back to `false`, the border pixel is set back to `1px` and the color is set back to static white.

This is what I have thus far:

HTML:

```
       $(document).on("click","tr", function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         $(e.currentTarget).attr("contenteditable", "true");
//         border: 1px solid black;
//         $('#'+e.currentTarget.id).css("border", "3px solid");

         for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
           $('#'+e.currentTarget.id)
            .animate( { backgroundColor: "#f00" }, 2000 ) //I need to change this to border color and thickness
            .animate( { backgroundColor: "transparent" }, 2000 );

         }
   //Then create an event to revert editions to normal : bordercolor: black, 
   //borderthickness: 1px, 
       });
```

I appreciate the help, if a solution can't be offered I would also appreciate directions to related docs.

Comment: $.animate() works only on CSS properties that have single numeric values. Thus, you only need to specify the border's width, as the border-color property is ignored by $.animate()

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16793360/jquery-animate-border-color-and-width

Comment: @claudio I did see that post, it is not the border's width that I want to animate it's the borders color, which I want to transition between two colors repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't without using plugins.

From http://api.jquery.com/animate/ 
"All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color plugin is used)"
And also considering that the "Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. font, background, border) are not fully supported."

You need a plugin to make the border color transition "the border-color property is ignored by $.animate()" method.
For example, try this: https://bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/ 
2.7kB minified.

So include the plugin

script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.color-animation/1/mainfile"

define the border rules on css

and do the animation you want one for property on the for loop:

.animate({borderColor: '#f00'}, 2000)
.animate({borderWidth : '3px’}, 2000)

Comment: Thanks for the help but when I try it the animation isn't displayed but when I check the console log it changes there. What do you think might be wrong?

Comment: strange .. I don't know where to start to isolate the problem. up to contenteditable true / false and then change border thickness without animation work?