# JQuery Css speed implementation

Tags: jquery, css

I want to make a border-bottom to my li with a speed. How can I solve this?

My code:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#mi").mouseover(function(){
            $("#mi").css({"border-bottom": "1px solid #fff"});
        },800);
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "with a speed"?

Comment: Do you mean you want the border to fade in? Use `.animate()`.

Comment: withput animation I want to make a border-bottom with a slow motion.

Comment: I think you have to use `.animate()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16793360/jquery-animate-border-color-and-width for an example.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mi").mouseover(function(){
    $("#mi").css({"border-bottom": "0px solid #fff"}).animate({
        borderbottom: 1
    }, 500);;
    });
});  I tried this but it doesnt work.

Comment: It should be `{borderBottomWidth: 1}`

Comment: Yes I got it now, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to animate the `border-bottom-width` property.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mi").mouseover(function() {
    $("#mi").css({
      "border-bottom": "0px solid #fff"
    }).animate({
      borderBottomWidth: 1
    }, 500);;
  });
});
```